# Delete from where record is like

Tags: mysql

everybody, i have a table like this:

```
id | img            
1  | 20/23/link.png 
2  | 20/24/link.png
3  | 20/23/link.png
```

I want to delete all records where ing starts with 20/23. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE IMG LIKE '20/23%'
```

You may have to set the safe update to 0.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

But set it back to 1 after you deleted records.

Comment: DELETE FROM table WHERE img like '20/23%' what is the difference between your command and this ?

Comment: why should i set it to 0 ? I have about + 200 000 records to delete will this be ok ?

Comment: This is for safety. So, users can not right away delete records.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the SQL command to do that:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE img like '20/23%'
```

The `%` means that this string should begin by '20/23' and then have any other caracters.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr

```
delete from my_table
where substr(img, 1, 5 ) = "20/23";
```